# Recursive call in OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I am trying to implement a recursive call in OCaml, using the next code :

```
| Add (x,y) -> 
  begin 
    match x, y with
        | x, Bra y ->  Bra (Implies(x, y))
        | x, Add (a, b) ->  Add(x, Add(a, b)) 
        | x, y ->  Implies(x, y)

  end
```

When testing it with 2 cases, I found that in the case 2 the program enters in an infinity loop.

1. `+(p,[] z)`
   it returns `[](p => z)`
2. `+(p,+(q,[] z))`
   it should return `[](p => (q => z))` , but instead of that goes inside the never ending loop.

I can see that the problem with case 2, is because I am calling `Add` inside another `Add` operator. But I understand here that the "exit" of the loop should be given by the first line of the match clause, however it is not working.

If you have any advice I would be grateful.
Just to clarify, I am using the next syntax for the operators

```
Add + , Bra [], Implies =>
```

Comment: the few lines of code you've provided do not contain a function call, let alone a recursive call. Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it will be extremely difficult to help you

Comment: Hi @Virgile, thank you for your answer , in fact what I am trying to do is generate a recursive structure, translating +(p,+(q,[] z)) to its equivalence sintax [](p => (q => z))

Comment: As @Virgile said, we do not see any (recursive) call or loop in your code, so we cannot say where the "never ending loop" comes from. Maybe show us your entire function ?

Comment: Just to make it clear `Add (a,b)` or `Implies (x,y)` is not a call, i.e., you're not calling any functions, you are applying a constructor to create a value of your operators language. A call (i.e., a function application) in OCaml looks like this `f x` or `add x y`, notice the uncapitalized first letter and the lack of any parentheses and commas.

Answer (score 2):

In this code extract, some value (let's say `v`) matches `Add (x,y)`. In particular, there is a case where `y` matches `Add (a, b)`. That means that `v` is equal to this value:

```
Add (x, Add (a, b))
```

But, notice that the return value of your function in this case is also:

```
Add (x, Add (a, b))
```

There, `v` is returned unchanged.

If your code loops until there is no more `Add` (I don't know, because the code is incomplete, please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), then this branch of your code produces a fixpoint, which may explain the infinite loop.